# problem in DismissPresentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am making a application in which i go from one view to another with presentModalViewController and from that view to another view with presentModalViewController now i want to go back (one view back ) with dismissModalViewController  and i called this method from appdelegate but it causing msg_trap error  ..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for this after long time of searching and googling  ,here we need to maintain a array for the each pushed controller and whenever we dismiss a controller  we should dismiss the object at index for that particular controller ..